Change (rename) original text object in scene after applying dissolve attributes
I'm new to Blender.
I have a scene with a text object (Happy Birthday) in caps, which has dissolve/particles  animation applied.
After all the attributes are applied, I cannot change or rename the original test from Happy Birthday to Kaiju. Only way I've found is to delete and start with new text, which takes a while to apply all the settings.
I'd like to use the same scene and animation for anniversary/bdays, but change names of people.
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much.
